# changes to javascript file "ignored" in VS2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, browser-cache

I have a javascript file `harSympCode.js` that I am trying to make changes to. It is used in 5 aspx pages - .NET 4.0 & VS2010 - and needs to remain consistent for all 5.

In the js file there is a function `startstop()` which triggers a floating clock to count. It is called in the onload event of the body tag. It works just fine. There is another function (call it `function1()`) which is supposed to load some values to a form. It is almost identical to a second one (call it `function2()`) in the file except the second one does a `form.submit()` when it is done. I am attempting to modify `function1()` to also submit the form when done BUT no matter what I do, I can not get the system (VS2010 localhost) to recognize the 2 lines of code I added. Since they are working just fine in `function2()` and I don't see any error codes or warnings when I rebuild the website, I can only guess that the changes are being ignored.

What I have tried:

1. Removed the `<script>` tag from the aspx pages: Result - `startstop()`, `function1()` and `function2()` are not found.
2. Added the `<script>` tag back in but removed the script file from the solution/project directory structure: Result - everything runs as if the file was still there.
3. Deleted sln and suo files and reopened the website while at the same time trying options 1 and 2: Results - same as 1 and 2.

I have looked through my entire directory structure and renamed and/or deleted every version of the js file I could find, to no avail.

I have looked for anything and everything related to precompiling a website (NOT application) and attempted to make changes to a supposed "Precompile" directory but  a) could not find the directory and  b) all changes I made were ignored and/or reset the next time I went and looked.

Has Anybody seen this and how did you fix it?

Comment: Probably a cached file. Ctrl+Shift+Delete and remove your cache and see if it persists. Alternatively you can use the developer window (F12) and click the clear cache button (window with a red X between cursor and floppy drive on the top left of the developer window on HTML tab). If you've already cleared cache, my apologies, but everything leads me to believe it's browser not IDE.

Comment: Check the code in Firebug and if necessary, single step to make sure the lines in question are really being executed.

Comment: is this actually a precompiled site? the standard today is to have access-time compilation (first run).

Answer (score 3):

This does not seem like an IDE issue as mentioned in your comment. Make sure you set your browser to refresh the cache on each load. In IE:

[image]

If you're using Chrome, then cache is cleared from the dev tools and is very persistent. Also refresh the page using ***CTRL+F5***. You also want to make sure that you're not getting compilation errors and your project isn't running from the previous working version. However point 1 of what you've tried suggests that the generated HTML page refreshes when you run your project but your browser cache contains the javascript files and so when the script tag exists it finds the cached ones and executes them. So you can use the 2nd button from the top (Clear Browser Cache...) to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I had been having this issue, clearing my cache and wondering why VS2010 kept looking at the old file, even though it appeared as the new version in F12.

The solution turned out to be that TFS had the file locked, and that once I checked out the javascript in question, the debugger picked up the new version.